# dojo request.del can not call success method

Tags: dojo

I user this code to call ajax by dojo.

```
request.del(url,{handleAs:'json'}).then(
       function(){console.log('success')},
       function(){console.log('error')}
);
```

when our server status is 200 ok, and no response, and our data was really deleted successfully.

But, the success callback would never be called.

The log 'success' or 'error' not happened.

Please help me for this, I don`t know if someone also meet this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors other than the lack of semicolons for the console.log statements. It would also be proper to add in the response parameters in the callback functions.

```
request.del(url,{handleAs:'json'}).then(
       function(data){console.log('success '+data);},
       function(err){console.log('error '+err);}
);
```

Comment: thanks, man.  
But it is not about the response param.  Although, we add param in the callback function, and the callback function still not be called...